# Set padding of a Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, padding

I have a Canvas with a Rectangle and a Circle inside it:

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasMain" Width="595" Height="842" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Tomato" Height="335" Canvas.Left="40" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="60" Width="265"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Tomato" Height="175" Canvas.Left="370" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="465" Width="200"/>
</Canvas>
```

I want to set Padding of the Canvas programmatically. Should I set the margin of all the elements inside the Canvas to achieve this purpose or is there any alternative

Comment: What would padding even mean in the context of a `Canvas` object? The whole point of `Canvas` is to provide a place where child objects are laid out using explicit X and Y values, not relative to anything except the `Canvas` itself. What effect are you trying to achieve that the `Canvas.Margin` property doesn't give you?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: `Canvas.Margin` reduces the size of the canvas. That may be undesired (e.g. if canvas has a  background).

Comment: @JanDotNet: I'm well aware of what `Canvas.Margin` does. But if `Canvas` had a padding property, it would also reduce the available layout size within the `Canvas`. So if it might be undesirable (as you claim), the OP wouldn't be asking for a way to set padding.

Comment: I am trying to create gap between the canvas border and the elements inside. One way is increasing the top,bottom,left and right value of all the elements inside and increase the height and width of the canvas accordingly. But in such case I have to run a loop to find each elements and reposition them each time i change the padding @Peter Duniho

Comment: _"I am trying to create gap between the canvas border and the elements inside "_ -- Canvases don't have borders. So what does it mean to create a gap in that non-existent place? And again, in what way does simply setting the `Margin` property _not_ do what you want? And please make sure you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45529007/edit) your question to improve and clarify it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho he probably meant something more abstract like canvas "boundary" rather than an explicitly visual border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set `Padding` of the `Canvas` programmatically. Should I set the margin of all the elements inside the `Canvas` to achieve this purpose or is there any alternative

It is either that or adjusting the coordinates (the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties) of the elements.

A `Canvas` has no concept of padding so you need to create the gap yourself somehow. There is no right or wrong really.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to put the canvas in a border.

```
<Border x:Name="rootBorder">
      <Canvas x:Name="CanvasMain" Width="595" Height="842" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

      </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Then you can set border's padding.

```
rootBorder.Padding = new Thickness(25);
```

Comment: Since the OP has not actually explained what they are trying to do, you have no reason to believe that the above actually addresses the question they asked. Furthermore, setting the padding of an element containing the `Canvas` doesn't really do anything that simply setting the `Canvas.Margin` property would do. So this isn't even a _good_ way to accomplish that specific behavior.

Comment: I know what he want to do and I agree with you use the Margin property should be the simply way.